# How to use a scope in Directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to use $scope variable in template function of directive like this.
In the other words i want to generate directive template inside of directive and by using $scope variable.

Help me to connect template function to controller.

```
directive("data", ['$compile', '$http', '$templateCache',function ($http,$rootScope) {
    return{
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.template = something // I want Generate template here
    },
    template:function(element , attrs){ 
        return $scope.template // I can't access scope here
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't access the scope in template function since the scope is not determined yet (it is run before link function). What exactly are you trying to achieve? There should be an alternative solution for your problem.

Comment: I know thit it isn't determined. And I wanna know how I connect between those.

Comment: The template function will be run before the link function, so you can't prepare the template in the link function.

Comment: does it mean isn't any way? I have a directive that is parent of this. I can i generate the template of child directive from parent and apply to child?

Comment: There are other ways to dynamically generate the template, one of them is to use `$compile` like in @Jaime answer. We couldn't help you find the best way unless we know exactly what are you trying to achieve. May be you could start with putting an expected result html as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not access to the scope in the template function, if you want to generate the template  somehow and then render the template inside the directive I'll suggest to use the [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) inside the link function in this way :

```
var a = angular.module('myApp', []);

a.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myTemplate = '<span class="custom-tpl"> my template </span>';
});

a.directive('dynamicTemplate', [ '$compile',

function ($compile) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            customTemplate: '='
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller) {
            var compiledTemplate = $compile($scope.customTemplate)($scope);
            $element.html('').append(compiledTemplate);
        }
    };

}]);
```

you can check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JaimeBeneytez/3d791ya6/)

Answer (score -1):

The `scope` option within `directives` provides an isolated scope to remove the scope issues from parent controller and provides the directive to be portable and decoupled with the controller. In your scenario you can define your isolated scope for template as below:

**JS Code:**

```
directive("data", ['$compile', '$http', '$templateCache',function ($http,$rootScope) {
 return{
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      template: '='
    }
    template:function(element , attrs){ 
        return scope.template;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<data template='something'></data>
```

This way of isolated scope provides the `binding strategies ('@', '=')` for one way or two-way data binding of scope variables to DOM. In your case `template` attribute in `data` element will be two-way data bound to `scope` variable `template`.

Comment: thanks. but in template function scope is undefined. How can i use this?