# Dynamic template URL with Angular 1.5 directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman-generator-angular

I am wanting to change my navbar template on a route change.

I have come up with two solutions, but I am not 100% satisfied with either.

1) I can define an ng-include outside of my view.

```
angular.module('automatclubApp')
  .directive('navbar', function (PartialsPath) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: 'NavbarCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'navCtrl'
    };
  })
  .controller('NavbarCtrl', function(PartialsPath,  $scope, $location) {
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(/* EDIT: remove params for jshint */) {
        var path = $location.path();
        //EDIT: cope with other path
        $scope.templateUrl = (path==='/') ? '../scripts/directives/partials/navbar.html' : '../scripts/directives/partials/navbar_lobby.html';
    });
  });
```

And then include this in my index:

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller='NavbarCtrl'>
      <div ng-include='templateUrl'></div>
    </div>
   <div ng-view=""></div>
</body>
```

2) In my views/main.html file, I can include an ng-include like this:

```
  <ng-include src="'../scripts/directives/partials/navbar.html'"></ng-include>
```

Ideally, I would love to have a directive declaration in my ng-view for a bit cleaner code. Any suggestions? It says my navbar controller is undefined when I can it in ng-view, which is why it seems solution one isn't working like I intended.

Comment: Is it helpful for you to use directive param `template: function (...){...}` ?

Comment: It's saying $scope.$on is not a function if I try to shift that logic just to template.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341641/how-to-use-a-scope-in-directive-template is a similar question.

Comment: That was a nice hint on getting access to compile, but I can't seem to apply a function to it without getting a max stack overload. angular.js:13920 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

This seems to be a bit of a sticky issue :) It seems to be difficult to put this this dynamic template route change inside the ng-view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution I am happy with.

Directive:

```
angular.module('automatclubApp')
  .controller('NavbarCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    // $scope.myTemplate = '<span class="custom-tpl" style="color: white"> my template </span>';
    $scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
      var path = $location.path();
      return path ==='/' ? '../scripts/directives/partials/navbar.html' : '../scripts/directives/partials/navbar_lobby.html';
    };
  })
  .directive('navbar', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()">'
    };
  });
```

Which can be invoked in the view like this:

```
<div ng-controller='NavbarCtrl'>
  <navbar></navbar>
</div>
```